# Yup - create and modify a validation schema at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, yup

I need to create a user and then update it. So I need two different schema.

This is the first one, for the user creation:

```
const addressSchema = object().shape({
    street: string().required(),
    city: string().required(),
});

const signUpSchema = object().shape({
    req: object().shape({
        username: string().trim().required(),
        password: string().trim().required(),
        role: string().trim().required(),
        address: addressSchema
            .default(null)
            .nullable()
            .when(role, isAdminRole(object().required()))
    })
})
```

Now, I would like to reuse the schema above for the customer's update operation. But, it can't be equals because in the update operation, for example, I don't want to change the password. Second, it can't have `.required()` restriction. Because, in the update operation, maybe, I want to modify only the username and not also the role. This is how the update schema should look like:

```
const addressUpdateSchema = object().shape({
    street: string().min(1), // .min(1) because it's not a required field but it can't be an empty string neither
    city: string().min(1),
});

const updateSchema = object().shape({
    req: object().shape({
        username: string().trim().min(1), 
        role: string().trim().min(1),
        address: addressUpdateSchema
            .default(null)
            .nullable()
            .when(role, isAdminRole(object()))
    })
})
```

In order to achieve these schemas, this is what I did:

1 - Creating an array of objects containing the validation fields:

```
const signUpValidationSchemaArray = [
{ name: 'username', validation: string().trim().required() },
{ name: 'password', validation: string().trim().required() }
{ name: 'role', validation: string().trim().required() }
{ name: 'address', validation: addressSchema.default(null).nullable().when(role, isAdminRole(object().required()))}
```

2 - Writing a function that returns a yup schema starting from the array above:

```
const buildYupSchema = (fields: any[]) => {
    const newSchema = {};
    fields.forEach(field => newSchema[field.name] = field.validation);
    return object().shape(newSchema);
}

buildYupSchema(signUpValidationSchemaArray);
```

Doing this we create the `const signUpSchema = object().shape({ ...` schema declared above.
Now, I want to create the `const updateSchema = object().shape({ ...`  schema using the already written code as much as possible.

3 - Here's the problem, I'm trying to modify the validation fields of signUpValidationSchemaArray

```
const updateValidationSchemaArray = [...signUpValidationSchemaArray].filter(field => field.name !== 'password' )
.map(field => {
        name: field.name,
        validation: field.validation.notRequired()
    }
});

buildYupSchema(updateValidationSchemaArray);
```

`.filter(field => field.name !== 'password' )` -> I want exclude password since I don't want to modify it in the update operation

`validation: field.validation.notRequired()` -> I want to remove required() restriction. I tried doing this, adding notRequired(); but it's not working. Maybe it would be better to remove .required() directly, somehow. But I don't know how to do this.

- Any suggestions?
- Is this a good approach to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I am using reactive if conditions for two , this works

```
let schema; // IMPORTANT!!!!!!!

$: if (editId && !blockUser && !resetPass) {
//validation for edit info
schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().required().email().label("Email"),
  mobile: yup
    .number()
    .typeError("Mobile is a requried field")
    .label("Mobile No"),
});
} else {
//validation for add
schema = yup.object().shape({
  full_name: yup.string().required().max(30).label("Full Name"),
  email: yup.string().required().email().label("Email"),
  password: yup.string().required().min(8).label("Password"),
  mobile: yup
    .number()
    .typeError("Mobile is a requried field")
    .label("Mobile No")
});
}
```